# Erlang node crashed with a message Internal error in copy_struct(): htop, hbot overrun

Tags: erlang

My erlang node  crashed with an error message

```
Internal error in copy_struct(): htop, hbot overrun
```

Are there any explanations what does it mean and how to avoid it?

Comment: Normally these types of errors are extremely rare. What version of the Erlang runtime are you running? You can obtain this by executing `erlang:system_info(version).` in an `erl` shell.

Comment: Hello, Steve, it is 7.3.

Comment: The root of the problem could be following: I have a folder with ind of 160000 files.  I call   {ok,FileNames} = file:list_dir(Path),
to get list of all files, and then convert names to binary using: list_to_binary. In most case this is work fine. File names are Latin1 charactes (0-9, a-z, _,-) Time to time I got an error message cannot convert list to binary and  File name looks like: [50,48,49,54,45,48,56,45,50,49,95,48,49,45,52,54,45,53,53,45,54,55,131129,95,50,48,49,54,45,48,56,45,50,49,95,48,49,45,52,54,45,53,54,45,51,53,57,95,68,83,84], where 121129 looks like an error.

Comment: I think you should try to make a test case that's as small as possible but still hits this crash, and then file it at [bugs.erlang.org](https://bugs.erlang.org/).

Comment: I tried to just process the same amount of files on a clean node. Everything has been working. Looks like it happened time-to-time and probably related to the memory allocation. :(

Comment: The error comes from copy.c in https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/3b7a6ffddc819bf305353a593904cea9e932e7dc/erts/emulator/beam/copy.c#L911 . It seems to be a sanity check the that the copying of an object hasn't used more space than it was expected to use. How much memory is the application using when this error occurs? Also, does it happen if you increase heap size (see http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/processes.html#Initial_heap_size) ?

Comment: I do not have a data about memory usage when it crashed. At the moments data looks like this:

Comment: Uptime  2 days, total memory 152 Mb, Processes 73 Mb, Binaries: 2MB, Ets 11Mb. And there are 4000 files processed. Base on this data, i would estimate that at time of crash Binaries consumed 80 MB. I could try to increase heap size, but fortunately it does not happened too often. I have checked and initial heap size is 333 words. What would be recommend heap size?